# Can you have two version of Visual Studio Code at the same time and use them simultaneously?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can you have multiple versions or copies of same version of Visual Studio Code on a device at the same time? I know we can use other alternatives like Codium, Sublime text, etc., But I would like to know whether there are any possibilities that we can use Visual Studio Code simultaneously.

The reason I'm asking this is because I'm currently studying some programming languages. I'm usually fixated on having a clean and proper platform for everything, as I'm currently using Visual Studio Code for my studies, I initially used it for my University portions and curriculum. That's why I'm wondering whether I can have separate Visual Studio Code versions or copies of it without it disturbing my University Visual Studio Code setup?

I have tried installing previous versions, it does not seems to work.

Comment: I can't imagine what kind of "interference" you are worried about.  The application is the application.  All the "tuning" you do can be done with local configuration files in your current directory -- they don't have to be global.  I believe you are overthinking this.

Comment: You can use a Visual Studio Code with version X and [Visual Studio Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) with version Y.

Answer (score 2):

Would this be of any help? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles

You can customize each profile to your liking. Switch to school profile when you are doing schoolwork, switch into personal when not.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific use-case, I'd suggest using [Profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles). You can define multiple profiles each with their own set of extensions, settings, keyboard shortcuts, global tasks, user snippets, etc.

But to answer the original question, I think yes. Just use [Portable VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable) and install multiple of it to different directories on your machine.